# When I switch a language in Opencart the decimal point is switching to letter "d" - wtf?

Tags: opencart, decimal-point

I'm desperate. I have a problem.. When I have ENG on my site turned on price looks like this -104.60€- but when I switch to SLOVAK, price suddenly looks like this -104d60€- - it shows the letter "d" instead of decimal point. Also there is Russian and German language preinstalled in this template and price on these two looks also ok. I've searched the net and only found one forum from like 4 years ago, but there was not a solution to this problem or what may cause it.

Look for yourselves -
link: http://eufrazia.sk/site/

I would really appreciate your HELP <3

Comment: Have you installed `SLOVAK` language or not? I think its not getting language file of that.

Comment: Yes, I did. You can see, that when you change the language from e.g. eng to slovak in header the top content changes the language from eng to slovak (I know there are some translations missing, but I will solve that later) - what worries me the most is this letter "d" instead of decimal point :/

Comment: That's not it man :/ Check the link, have english switched on, scroll down check the products and its prices (it will look like this eg. 120.43$) then change the language to slovak in top of the site, scroll down and check the price - you will see for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change language text of `decimal_point` in your language file i.e in `catalog/language/slovak/slovak.php` and change `$_['decimal_point']  = 'd';` to `$_['decimal_point'] = '.';`
That's it.

Comment: I've opened the file and the code is same as you proposed 

" $_['decimal_point']         = '.'; "

but the directory looks like this 

catalog/language/slovak/default.php ---> the file is called default.php and not slovak.php ---> does it matter or should I change it to "slovak.php" ?

Comment: should be same as your language directory name. So change it to `slovak.php`

Comment: Guys, I love you. Thank you, it worked.

I renamed the file from default.php to slovak.php and it works now !

Bless you